# I control the gameobject by tilting the phone and need to keep it balanced in whatever the rotation of the phone is when game starts

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I published a game named Rotate Ball Pro last week. But some people told me that playing the game was not so comfortable.
I used unity and C# for coding. My game levels has labyrinths and a sphere on it. The sphere has rigidbody component but the labyrinths have not. So you can control the labyrinth by tilting the phone and thus the sphere can roll. But you must hold the phone parallel to the ground to keep the labyrinth balanced. For example you can not play by lying on back or holding the phone with any angle. So this makes playing uncomfortable.
I want to to keep the labyrinth balanced in whatever the rotation of the phone is when the game starts. I searched web and tried many things but could not solve it. Can anyone help me?

Here is the explanation of the problem with an image: [Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9hMw6.png)

Here is the direct game link: [Rotate Ball Pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.UmbrellaSK.RotateBallPro)

Here is my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[System.Serializable]

public class NewMovementScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float multiplier = 0;
    void Start()
    {
        Input.gyro.enabled = true;
        Screen.sleepTimeout = SleepTimeout.NeverSleep;
    }
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        var dir = Vector3.zero;
        dir.x = Input.acceleration.x * -1 * multiplier;
        dir.y = Input.acceleration.z * multiplier;
        dir.z = Input.acceleration.y * multiplier;
        transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(dir.z, 0f, dir.x);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[`Input.acceleration`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input-acceleration.html) is the **position** change between the last and current frame and as you noted already doesn't take the initial state into account.

This also is barely related to rotations at all.

I think for your usage you would rather simply use [`Input.gyro.attitude`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Gyroscope-attitude.html)!

Example from the docs

> ```
> public class Example : MonoBehaviour
> {
>     // Rotate the object to match the device's orientation
>     // in space.
>     void Update()
>     {
>         transform.rotation = Input.gyro.attitude;
>     }
> }
> ```

If your object uses a rigidbody you might want to rather use

```
public class Example : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Rigidbody rigidbody;

    void Awake ()
    {
        rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        rigidbody.MoveRotation(Input.gyro.attitude);
     }
}
```